# How to mount existing Jenkins directory onto a Jenkins Docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

The DevOps person before me set up a Jenkins service on a Ubuntu Linux box, and it uses `/var/lib/jenkins` as the `JENKINS_HOME` directory. Now I want to run a `jenkins/jenkins:lts` Docker container to use the same directory as its `JENKINS_HOME`, so I try to do the following on the Linux host.

```
$ service jenkins stop
$ docker run --rm -it -p 8880:8080 --name jenkins -v /var/lib/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

But I get

```
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
```

This is a valid way to do it correct? If so, how can I fix this error so I can run the Jenkins container using the current Jenkins service files? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "host" jenkins `user:group` id's are different from the "container" jenkins `user:group` id. Since I don't plan to ever start the `jenkins` service on the host, I did the following on the host

```
$ service jenkins disable
$ chown -R 1000:1000 /var/lib/jenkins
```

where `1000:1000` are the `user:group` id's of the jenkins user on the container. Then the `docker run...` command I have in my post worked.